# Are 'role' attributes necessary in HTML5?

Tags: html, wai-aria

In trying to keep up with HTML5, I've made sure to validate all of my markups by using the [W3 validator tool](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea). Recently, I've started to add the `role` attribute to elements. However, I've noticed the following warnings pop-up time and again:

> The `button` role is unnecessary for element `button`.
>
> The `navigation` role is unnecessary for element `nav`.

But on the same token, on the W3C website regarding ARIA in HTML, it states that the [`button` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#button) is applicable to the `<button>` element and that the [`navigation` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#nav) is **only** applicable to the `<nav>` element.

This brings me to my question, are the `role` attributes necessary with the role out of HTML5? What would I have a scenario that I would need to use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [first rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1) states:

> If you can use a native HTML element [HTML51] or attribute with the
>   semantics and behaviour you require already built in, instead of
>   re-purposing an element and adding an ARIA role, state or property to
>   make it accessible, then do so.

If you view the [navigation role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#navigation) in WAI-ARIA, it states that [HTML Nav](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#elementdef-nav) is a related concept and that `navigation=role` is already the default role, so there is no need to set it manually yourself:

> Allowed ARIA role attribute values:
>       navigation role (default - do not set).

So the navigation role **is** applicable to the `<nav>`, but it's already set by default so you don't need to do it yourself.

In summary to your question, no, don't set roles if they are already implied within the semantics of HTML5. You can check out the website below which I think outlines some good points as to when you should/shouldn't use ARIA (it's not all about the role attribute, but it does cover that as well):
[What is WAI-ARIA, what does it do for me, and what not?](https://www.marcozehe.de/2014/03/27/what-is-wai-aria-what-does-it-do-for-me-and-what-not/)

Answer (score 1):

The article may also be helpful [On HTML belts and ARIA braces (The Default Implicit ARIA semantics they didn’t want you to know about)](http://html5doctor.com/on-html-belts-and-aria-braces/)